# Using COM for RPC from C++ to C#

Tags: c#, c++, winapi, com, rpc

I need to implement a class in C++ that can call a C# function from unmanaged C++ and return a value. I've done this from C++ to C++ using MIDL/RPC binding over named pipe which works great but now my server application is moving to C# but the client must remain unmanaged C++ (it's an explorer extension).

I've looked at various methods and lots of people suggest COM, it was my understanding that COM was not so much for IPC/RPC but for hosting a served object in a client app. Is this going to be possible with COM, if so, can anyone point me in the direction of a good reference or example?

EDIT:

Just to be clear, I cannot use managed code as the client (DLL) is loaded into Explorer's process space.

What I am trying to achieve is when the user right-clicks on a file the extension will ask a running service (session 0) for some details about the file. This was previously done via RPC in a C++ <-> C++ client/server. Now the server has been upgraded to C# but I'm not sure what my options are. Is COM an option?

Thanks,
J

Comment: COM uses RPC when necessary, in out-of-process or cross-apartment cases.  Not having to wrangle RPC is of course very nice.  There are not enough details in your question to even tell if this applies.

Comment: Edited to include some more details.

Answer (score 2):

Use mixed CLR and native C++ DLL. Check [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms173266%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) and [tools](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/x0w2664k.aspx).

[*Native and .NET Interoperability*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/zbz07712.aspx)

Comment: I can't use the CLR in my extension as it is loaded into the Explorer process space. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/junfeng/archive/2005/11/18/494572.aspx

Comment: @JWood: What do you want to use from .net? Own module?

Comment: I need to call a function in a running C# service to retrieve information about a file when the user right-clicks in Explorer. WCF achieves this nicely via named pipes but how can unmanaged C++ call a function in a running C# service?

Comment: @JWood: for IPC I usually use TCP/IP and XML. They are future proof and system independent.

Comment: It doesn't need to be system independent, this is Windows only and there is a lot of overhead involved with building TPC/IP and XML libraries into an Explorer extension. This was going to be my last resort but with COM being suggested often I wanted to explore the possibility.

Comment: @JWood: named shared memory, event and mutex? It is more effective and don't get the COM's coding hell.

Comment: Actually I found a very useful post which has at least shown that it is possible to do what I need with C#/DOM - http://www.andymcm.com/?p=15

Comment: I wish you elaborated an answer for future reference instead of posting a link which is now dead (redirects to a domain for sale).